# Apple script to run a shell script to get around permissions

Tags: macos, bash, shell, applescript

I have created a shell .command on Mac OS X that I would like to distribute. Based on my testing, you can't execute the .command file by double clicking without changing permissions first ( making executable. ) I don't want users to use the terminal and change permissions, it's too hard for them.

The shell script creates a folder structure for a project, based on where the script is. It needs to be able to run anywhere the user puts it.

The research I have done indicates that I need to use an Apple script to run the file to prompt for the user's password to get around permissions.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: If you distribute it via zip or dmg, does that not preserve permissions?

Comment: Face-palm. That is the way to do it! I'll use this method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribute the file either by zip or DMG - props Thilo.